# What if you smoked normal cigarettes during the 40 days before Ramadan, does fasting Ramadan not count just like alcohol?

Tags: halal-haram, sawm, ramadan

What if I smoked normal cigarettes during the 40 days before Ramadan would it count for me if I start fasting during Ramadan or is it the same as when you drink alcohol where the  praying and fasting doesn’t count for 40 days?

Comment: As far as I’m aware, it’s best not to indulge in either.

Comment: I'd wonder if any statemt about 40 days holds a cross check with qur'an and sahih sunnah! Why would Allah reject the deeds of a person, who might have repented just because of his former misdeeds? This doesn't sound logical.

Answer (score -2):

performing any haram actions such as smoking will make your fasting not count if you feel the need to smoke i suggest buying these off ebay(https://www.ebay.com/itm/Quit-Smoking-Aid-Natural-Stop-Smoking-Remedy-To-Help-Stop-Cravings-3-Pack/282737333710?_trkparms=ispr%3D1&hash=item41d47555ce:g:214AAOSwj8Vcmw0L&amdata=enc%3AAQAFAAACkBaobrjLl8XobRIiIML1V4Imu%252Fn%252BzU5L90Z278x5ickk7PdDazAlGltMLJlUhrWsD8AYcSLkSdHxChEehii6poFAPoJPLeTEI%252BDucxH1X9Fe66VLBH7eafwJJtMA3z%252F7Bq4P3Y4BcBz6F0DNTqJlPVUgVitpasdMjJXUKCXipSQDsrZReTCDlPfxlZgH2J2faLPC6xOgq6xQn1bmdW3f0w4AdLCJNxCVx3p9HbkG5JPforPmesJ%252FeCc4XkhyS2OLAFvfjMceYNMQ8msP1nCETMmQ4%252Bl0%252BI4FJVg9e12VSZodYCmGLe4sf3xs9VsqGanQ558Mk9j7gDEC6Y2ijBWRZWWg8d5rQgQ5de7zOPLWBkZpQfUPwAJbtAwW7PARMmfacZt7r479MtZfUu%252FiHx0yb9%252BVVmxgXcvOdk%252B1elq%252BCAztVkESZyJMFcKxoCzRbl7NGZoFA2AUye%252F5HA%252FiktCl0ZtnizSxOTgh9oddP36NHNm9hzJLN5a3yw0iewb%252FPXR%252BBF1ijM1mHj8wNh7OHlvXoDVZJvXBK%252F5NHhiHt87V4jfvoRi3m3cLTwW4aZcvaANub2jQTXfjcdkvBYu%252B6lw%252FJAwBU8PxBhBhfDtC7WVK8QLeLhlWUDK%252FCgOj0e%252FDFdpLWRtxNKflgjkUpyWbsAwFaRi7OMJMPJcruPm8Es1KxTySetkkxjaBnM7t%252FnMx5v04VCewY%252FRXn4EPTSEgp%252B8qJqtD6gVlkmCAtle%252BVeRl5DzMJOtvsuC0xXB2vKZ6CM3rRqVG3Gg1YM9lhxZBQOTVD3x7dvis2eO8NbeHgud1spR6zFu9VHNmnWS4%252FdAcKxAJ6kV9hSzPO4Qo4u402H2%252BI1k3laE6fb3ue5Zh%252BXvGgmEQ%7Ccksum%3A282737333710ed7353e47a8440a080d9d4f1a5e00d34%7Campid%3APL_CLK%7Cclp%3A2334524)they help you stop smoking and they make you feel like you are while in reality you are just inhaling clean air